# how to remove laravel with composer on linux mint 18.3(ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: laravel, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get, linux-mint

I install Laravel with the default composer

```
sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel 5.6
```

then I found a lot of error cause the compose is version 1.0x so old

then I remove the composer and update the composer to version 1.7.2

the question is how can I remove the bad laravel?

Can I just del the laravel directory?

I try

```
    sudo apt-get purge  laravel
sudo apt-get purge  laravel/laravle
sudo apt-get purge  laravel/laravel laravel 5.6
```

it shows cannot find the laravel

my var/www/html/laravel composer.json is below

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "~1.1",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
```

Comment: @you can directly delete laravel folder or just give a try with composer update to laravel folder'

Comment: I rm -f the laravel folder. And use  composer create-project laravel/laravel comes 5.6  But I got the erroe message----Cannot create cache directory /home/rb/.composer/cache/repo/http---repo.packagist.org/, , or directory is not eritable. Proceeding without cache

Comment: looks like permission issue'

Answer (score -2):

```
$composer remove laravel/laravel
```

this can solve this question!